# how to add all the numbers together and only display one line in a display text box?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1

    Private strDeskSold(3) As String

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim intQtySold As Integer

        If rbtnEast.Checked Then
            strDeskSold(0) = "East"
        Else
            strDeskSold(0) = "West"
        End If

        If rbtnLarge.Checked Then
            strDeskSold(1) = "Large L Shape"
        ElseIf rbtnSmall.Checked Then
            strDeskSold(1) = "Small L Shape"
        ElseIf rbtnExec.Checked Then
            strDeskSold(1) = "Executive"
        Else
            strDeskSold(1) = "Presidential"
        End If

        If rbtnEast.Checked Then
            If lstBoxManagers.Text = "Anna Banes" Then
                strDeskSold(2) = "Anna Banes"
            ElseIf lstBoxManagers.Text = "Charlie Deer" Then
                strDeskSold(2) = "Charlie Deer"
            End If
        End If

        If rbtnWest.Checked Then
            If lstBoxManagers.Text = "Dan Easom" Then
                strDeskSold(2) = "Dan Easom"
            ElseIf lstBoxManagers.Text = "Fran Granger" Then
                strDeskSold(2) = "Fran Granger"
            ElseIf lstBoxManagers.Text = "Hamp Ideal" Then
                strDeskSold(2) = "Hamp Ideal"
            End If
        End If

        Integer.TryParse(txtNumberSold.Text, intQtySold)

        strDeskSold(3) = intQtySold.ToString
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text & strDeskSold(0) & ControlChars.Tab & strDeskSold(1) & ControlChars.Tab & strDeskSold(2) & ControlChars.Tab & strDeskSold(3) & ControlChars.NewLine
    End Sub
```

The program allows a user to select a region, then the manager for that region, then the desk type, then the number of desks ordered. I want to display all the information in one line and then another line as they press add again if the information is different in a display only text box. I have no clue where to even begin to add the different quantities ordered to display the total desks that have been ordered for each different desk type.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, you want to display separate lines for each sale added unless the same item is sold by the same manager. In which case, you want to add the last sale to quantity to the existing sales in the list?

In which case, you need to go about it a slightly different way ..

---

Create a sale class like this

```
Private Class Sale
    Public Property Item As String
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
    Public Property ManagerName As String
End Class
```

And a manager class like this. Each manager will have their own list of sales.

```
Private Class Manager
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Region As String
    Public Property Sales As New List(Of Sale)
End Class
```

And create a list of managers

```
Dim Managers As New List(Of Manager)
```

This form load event will add all the managers to the list. You can include it of you wish or write your own code depending on how you store the managers.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim manager1 As New Manager With {.Name = "Anna Barnes", .Region = "West"}
    Dim manager2 As New Manager With {.Name = "Charlie Deer", .Region = "West"}
    Dim manager3 As New Manager With {.Name = "Dan Easom", .Region = "East"}
    Dim manager4 As New Manager With {.Name = "Fran Granger", .Region = "East"}
    Dim manager5 As New Manager With {.Name = "Hamp Ideal", .Region = "East"}
    Managers = New List(Of Manager) From {manager1, manager2, manager3, manager4, manager5}
End Sub
```

These two events repopulate the ListBox when you change the east/west checkbox selection

```
Private Sub RbtnEast_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RbtnEast.CheckedChanged
    If RbtnEast.Checked Then
        lstBoxManagers.DataSource = Managers.FindAll(Function(x) x.Region = "East").ToArray
        lstBoxManagers.DisplayMember = "Name"
        lstBoxManagers.Update()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RbtnWest_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RbtnWest.CheckedChanged
    If RbtnWest.Checked Then
        lstBoxManagers.DataSource = Managers.FindAll(Function(x) x.Region = "West").ToArray
        lstBoxManagers.DisplayMember = "Name"
        lstBoxManagers.Update()
    End If
End Sub
```

When you click the add button, the code creates a temporary sale item with all the details and if everything apart from the sales quantity matches a previous sale by a manager. If so, it will add the quantity of that sale to the preveious one. If there is no previous sale, it will be added to the manager's list of sales. Finally the richTextBox is updated to show a total sales of each item by each manager.

```
Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
    Dim tempSale As New Sale
    If rbtnLarge.Checked Then
        tempSale.Item = "Large L Shape"
    ElseIf rbtnSmall.Checked Then
        tempSale.Item = "Small L Shape"
    ElseIf rbtnExec.Checked Then
        tempSale.Item = "Executive"
    Else
        tempSale.Item = "Presidential"
    End If
    Integer.TryParse(TxtNumberSold.Text, tempSale.Quantity)
    Dim mgr As Manager = Managers.Find(Function(x) x.Name = CType(lstBoxManagers.SelectedItem, Manager).Name)
    'If Not IsNothing(mgr.Sales) Then
    Dim matchingSale As Sale = mgr.Sales.Find(Function(x) x.Item = tempSale.Item)
    If Not IsNothing(matchingSale) Then
        matchingSale.Quantity += tempSale.Quantity
    Else
        mgr.Sales.Add(tempSale)
    End If
    UpdateSalesTextBox()
End Sub
```

This is the update code. It iterates through all the managers and all of their sales totals for each unique item they've sold.

```
Private Sub UpdateSalesTextBox()
    rtbDisplay.SuspendLayout()
    rtbDisplay.Clear()
    For Each mgr As Manager In Managers
        For Each [sale] As Sale In mgr.Sales
            rtbDisplay.AppendText(mgr.Region & vbTab & [sale].Item & vbTab & mgr.Name & vbTab & [sale].Quantity & vbCrLf)
        Next
    Next
    rtbDisplay.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

If an answer sorts out your problem, don't forget to click the tick next to the answer - It makes sure that the user gets reputation points and makes it easier for anyone else who has the same problem to see that your question has an accepted answer that might work for them as well. (And the person answering the question gets reputation points btw)